# How to read streaming datasets from socket?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

Below code reads from a socket, but I don't see any input going into the job. I have `nc -l 1111` running, and dumping data though, not sure why my Spark job is not able to read data from `10.176.110.112:1111`.

```java
Dataset<Row> d = sparkSession.readStream().format("socket") 
                                    .option("host", "10.176.110.112")
                                    .option("port", 1111).load();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Below code reads from a socket, but I don't see any input going into the job.

Well, honestly, you do **not** read anything from anywhere. You've only described what you are **going to** do when you start the streaming pipeline.

Since you use Structured Streaming to read datasets from a socket, you should use [start](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@start():org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery) operator to trigger data fetching (and that's only after you define the sink).

> **start(): StreamingQuery** Starts the execution of the streaming query, which will continually output results to the given path as new data arrives. The returned StreamingQuery object can be used to interact with the stream.

Before `start` you should define where to stream your data. It could be Kafka, files, a custom streaming sink (perhaps using `foreach` operator) or console.

I use `console` sink (aka format) in the following example. I also use Scala and leave rewriting it to Java as your home exercise.

```
d.writeStream.  // <-- this is the most important part
  trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds")).
  format("console").
  option("truncate", false).
  start         // <-- and this
```